# Excel pivot table grouping and sorting by month in chronological order

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table where I want to arrange the columns into 12 months in chronological order. 
Easy when working on a standard yearly calendar but this is a fiscal year running Jul to Jun.

So the column headings should run

`JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN`

This comes from a sales table with many thousands of lines

I've even tried creating an extra column in the table formatted to mmm-yy and using that as the column source on the pivot

Excel insists that the year runs from January 2018 to December 2017

The only way I've come close is to group by year and month and then hide the year

EDIT
There was a request for sample data

The data that I'm using is really quite simple - it's basic sales data exported from our ERP

`ID    Customer  Item Name  Quantity  Date        Month
 001   C1        Widget            2  01/07/2018  Jul-18
 ...
 ...
 767   C23       Spiggot           7  05/04/2019  Apr-19`

I want to pivot this to show items sold by month of the fiscal year

Comment: Could you provide a sample about the data source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try adding another column to setup the correct order of months. The formula I have in mind would look like this. =IF(MONTH(A1)>=7,MONTH(A1)-6,MONTH(A1)+6) (assuming the date is in column A.

From there I would setup my pivot table with both the ordering month as the key header and actual under that. From there you could hide the ordering header leaving only the month.

I hope this helps.
Brad

Comment: Thanks, that works, much like my current approach of grouping by year and then hiding the grouping line. I guess I was hoping though that I was missing something obvious and that excel could work out for itself that July 2018 does not follow hot on the heels of June 2019

Comment: Glad it helped.